# ANCM in process handler failure in Dotnet core 3.0.1(Blazor) blazor app

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I created a project using blazor then published it and hosted it in [hostgator](https://hostgator.com), when I visit the url get the error `HTTP 500.0 In-process handler load failure` I found some related answers here but all were on Dotnet 2.2 which describing modification to `web.config` file, Dotnet 3.0.1 doesn't have `web.config` file instead it's `appsetting.json` please do I fix this 
in my own case now do I have to add the web.config myself, please I need help thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unless they have ASP.NET Core 3.1 hosting in place then they don't support it.  Therefore Blazor is TU on that host. From what it looks like that don't have it installed without asking about it from their support once that is done then you will have what you need.  My guess is they don't support it.

Comment: Okay thanks, let me contact them to be sure they support ASP.NET CORE 3.1